# Iframe not able to interact with Main Page in Iphone

Tags: javascript, ios, jsp, web, iframe

I have a web application that runs as mix of server side rendering and client side rendering, Where common component(side nav and top nav) are rendered via server side rendering and individual pages(content of page) are loaded by client side rendering using React embedded in iframe inside main page.

Authentication and Authorization is controlled via webapp which serves the JSP for Top Nav and Side Nav.

And individual pages(inside iframe) calls and listens to the event provided by main frame.

This is working fine in chrome and other browsers, but is not working on Safari.
And on mobile It is working on all android device but not working even on chrome in Iphone

In console I am seeing below error
`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: subscribeAbleEvents`
These events are defined in main page served via jsp. Seems like it is not allowing this to be accessed inside iframe.

I tried to deep dive and probable reason I found with sandbox parameter, We are not using sandbox with iframe. I also added sandbox parameter with all possible value allowed to test these, but it is also not working.

Any special security policy that is applied in safari / Iphone?

Answer (score 0):

use the object tag instead `<object data="URL" width="width_here" height="height_here"></object>` tell me if it works or not

Comment: instead of <iframe> ?

Comment: @Ravi yes but don't replace it in case it doesn't work

Comment: Tried changing tag... Entire page is accessing element with iframe tag, So not sure if we will be able to change tag itself